# My page views counter is incrementing 1 unit on my homapage but is incremented 3 units on secondary pages

Tags: php

Im doing a function to count visitors, views and page_views.

For now Im just trying to count page views but Im having a strange issue.

I have a table stats with this columns: "users,visits,page_views".

And now I just want to increment my page_views when user acess some page.

Every time I acess my homepage my page_views is incremented 1 unit, but when I acess a secundary page my column page_views is incremented with 3 units, and I want just also 1 unit.

Do you know why this can be happening?

I think that problem is in my getHome() function, because If I call my function countViews() before or after my getHome(), I have different behaviors.  But Im not finding why.

When I have me countViews() above my getHome(), It seems that Im calling 3 times my function countViews on my secundary pages.

But I only call my function countViews() on my index.php file and below this function I have my getHome() function where I do my navigation to all pages  I have in my project.

```
function countViews(){
    $pdo = start();
    //if Im not logged as admin
    if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
        //So at first I read my table stats, if my table dont have any row,
        // I create a row with my columns with value of '0'.
        $readStats= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM stats"); 
        $readStats->execute();  

        if($readStats->rowCount()<1){
            $insStats= $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO stats(users, views, page_views) VALUES (?,?,?)");
            $insStats->bindValue(1,'0');
            $insStats->bindValue(2,'0');
            $insStats->bindValue(3,'0');
            $insStats->execute();
        }
       //If my table stats already have one row, I want to increment page_views.  
        else{
            $resultStats= $readStats->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $incrementPageViews = $resultStats['page_views'] + 1;
            $updatePageViews =  $pdo->prepare("UPDATE stats set page_views = ?");
            $updatePageViews ->bindParam(1,$incrementPageViews);
            $updatePageViews ->execute();
        }

    }
}
```

My index.php is like:

```
<?php
  ob_start(); session_start();
  require_once('dts/db.php');
  $pdo = start();
  countViews();
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE>
 <!-- here I have my css and js imports -->

<?php getHome(); ?>
```

My secundary pages:

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head> 
 <body>
 <!-- here I have my html -->
 </body>
```

getHome() function:

```
<?php
function getHome(){
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    $url[0] = ($url[0] == NULL ? 'index' : $url[0]);

    if(file_exists('project/'.$url[0].'.php')){
        require_once('project/'.$url[0].'.php');
    }
    elseif(file_exists('project/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php')){
        require_once('project/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php');
    }
    else{
        require_once('project/404.php');
    }
}

?>
```

My table is like:

[image]

Comment: The problem is presumably in the callers to the function, not the function definition. I don't know how you expect us to tell why you're calling the function multiple times.

Comment: BTW, you should learn how to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` so you don't need the `SELECT` query.

Comment: You still aren't providing enough information. The problem is with the secondary pages, right? So show us what they look like.

Comment: Thanks for your help Barmar! Sorry, but I didnt understand your "you should learn how to use INSERT...". Im still a beginner in php and I usually do my inserts as I have in my question. I update my question with what I have in my secundary pages, but I think that they do not have anything that could be causing this issue.

Comment: `page_views = ?` instead use `page_views = page_views + 1` and you won't have to bind anything to the php.

Comment: You should add a primary key to the `stats` table. Then do `INSERT INTO stats (stats_id, users, views, page_views) VALUES (1, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE page_views = page_views + 1`.

Comment: There has to be some way that loading a secondary page causes you to run a script that updates the `stats` table. Things like this don't just happen spontaneously. Search all your scripts for references to the `stats` table. But there's no way for us to tell from here what's going on, you can only find it by searching your code.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for your clarification. Relative to main issuse, the only thing that might be causing it think it can only be my getHome function (). But I dont see how!

Comment: Why don't you pre-create the pages instead of trying to create it on the fly if there are no records to a given page?

Comment: Can you explain better your question? Sorry, I didnt understand clearly.

Comment: Can you show exactly how you're calling `getHome` in secondary pages?

Comment: I just call getHome() on my index.php file, and this function will call my secundary pages...

Comment: What function calls your secondary pages?

Comment: Do you have a redirect / Header('Location:..') in the sub page. The behaviour would be explained if you got redirected into the sub-page as it counts and then redirects. Or that page doesn't exist and hits the "404" and the 404 tries to find the right page for you. Otherwise, it's impossible to say without seeing  'project/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php' and 'project/404.php' content.

Comment: Call the `countViews()` function inside your sub pages .. after any header redirect code ..

Comment: This isn't the answer you asked for, but binding guaranteed database resources 1:1 to page hits is a nasty idea.  An angry visitor can flood your page with requests, and your database (which certainly backs other things?) will likely crumble, and distributed or not, your app stack can die.  Why not rely on Google Analytics?  You can track pages very granularly, even clicks on pages, at a zero resource cost and more importantly: no risk.  The pages will only track when they should, since the JS will only run when a page loads, and not on a header redirect.

Answer (score 3):

I have no clue why this is happening but I can help you find.

Do the following inside your countViews():

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump("Count Views beeing called from : ".__FILE__);
echo "</pre>";
```

If you still cannot find why using this, tell me and I will help you setup xdebug and profiling which will tell you exactly the files included and the functions called in the order they were called/included.

Like this:
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BGYXo-b-bj8/TvIjJd0pBXI/AAAAAAAAF_0/ZssGFW9Rb7Y/s1600/drupal-6-cacherouter-memcache-fail.png

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get this: string(74) "Count Views beeing called from : F:\Xampp\htdocs\website\code\functions.php". This functions.php is where I have all my functions.

Comment: Does he dumps it 3 times when you put the countViews() after the getHome() and access secondary pages?

Comment: No, just dumps one time!

Comment: You could also use this technique to trace all call paths leading to `countViews` throughout your application lifecycle.

Answer (score 2):

You route all 404 requests to  index.php . It seems you have 2 missed resource on secondary pages.
Try to modify countViews() function as below:

```
function countViews(){
    $tmp = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // huge logging: $tmp = print_r($_SERVER, 1);
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/viewslog.txt', $tmp, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );

    $pdo = start();
```

Answer (score 1):

There're two possibilities I can think of.

1. You have countViews in one of your `require_once` files
2. You have some redirect code in your secondary pages.

What I'm actually saying is, I'm sure it's not magic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chibueze Opata. But now, I just countViews on my index.php file. And in my secundary pages I dont have ant redirect code. My getHome() function that is called on my index.php file, do all my navigation, and I just call it on index.php file.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is changing your function into simpler one and check if this problem still occurs.

```
function countViews(){
    $pdo = start();
    //if Im not logged as admin
    if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
        //So at first I read my table stats, if my table dont have any row,
        // I create a row with my columns with value of '0'.
        $sth= $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM stats LIMIT 1"); 
        $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!$result){
            $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO stats(users, views, page_views) VALUES (0,0,0)");

        }
       //If my table stats already have one row, I want to increment page_views.  
        else{
            $pdo->exec("UPDATE stats set page_views = page_views + 1");

        }

    }
}
```

If it still doesn't work you should show us what data you have in your `stats` table.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I still have same problem. Can understand really what is going on. Can be because my .htaccess file?

Comment: @Marby rather not, but it's hard to say. I think the best if you could put your small application for example to github and we could run it on our PC and test what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I would start looking at your server's log, it could tell you wich files are being requested, it seems like some files are being requested more than once.